# How to read specific blocks of data file within certain keywords

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have a text data file that looks as shown below:

```
BEGIN_CYCLE
..
start_data
2d_data1
end_data
..
..
END_CYCLE

BEGIN_CYCLE
..
start_data
2d_data2
end_data

BEGIN_CYCLE
..
start_data
2d_data3
end_data
...
END_CYCLE

and so on
```

I am only interested in data blocks that start with **start_data** and end with **end_data** keywords, AND fall between **BEGIN_CYCLE** *and a matching* **END_CYCLE** keywords. In the above example, I want to read *2d_data1* and *2d_data3*. Notice that although *2d_data2* starts with start_data and ends with end_data keywords, it is NOT bound by BEGIN_CYCLE and a matching END_CYCLE keyword. It only has a BEGIN_CYCLE and no matching END_CYCLE keyword. Of course I can have any number of begin and end cycles, and not just 3. My code below still reads 2d_data2 and actually skips over 2d_data3, and reads subsequent data blocks correctly. I do not know why exactly this is happening.

```
indexes = []
with open(file) as f:        
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('BEGIN_CYCLE'):
            s = i
        elif line.startswith('END_CYCLE'):
            e = i
            indexes.append((s, e))  
        else:
            pass   

    temp_list = [list(range(*idx)) for idx in indexes]
    indexes = [item for sublist in temp_list for item in sublist]


    
data = []
with open(file) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if 'start_data' in line and i in indexes:
            chunk = []
            for line in f:
                if not line.startswith('end_data'):
                    chunk.append(''.join(line.strip().split()))
                else:
                    break
            data.append(chunk)
```

My thought process is to first identify valid test cycles (those with begin_cycle and end_cycle keywords) which explains the first part of the code. Then within these bounds, I am searching for start_data and end_data keywords and appending lines of data into chunks which I eventually collect in a list of data. The problem with my code is that 2d_data2 is read and not ignored. In fact, the code works fine whenever the test file always has matching BEGIN_CYCLE and END_CYCLE keywords. However, as soon as there is one or more instances of missing END_CYCLE keywords, then instead of ignoring any data block under that cycle, it includes it. Any help or alternative solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below works exactly like I wanted. However, I don't like the idea of opening the file each time I loop over the indexes. I cannot think of a fix for this.

```
    indexes = []
    with open(file) as f:        
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.startswith('BEGIN_CYCLE'):
                s = i
            elif line.startswith('END_CYCLE'):
                e = i
                indexes.append((s, e))  
            else:
                pass  

    data = []   
    for idx in indexes: 
        with open(file) as f:
            for line in itertools.islice(f, idx[0], idx[1]):
                if line.startswith('start_data'):
                    chunk = []
                    for line in f:
                        if not line.startswith('end_data'):
                            chunk.append(''.join(line.strip().split()))
                        else:
                            break
                    data.append(chunk)
```